# pywinauto print_control_identifiers only detect the title name - no automation id

Tags: python, pywinauto, inspector

I try to use `print_control_identifiers` with `pywinauto` module but the result just application title

This is the source code

```py
from pywinauto import Application, Desktop
app = Application().start(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Pandora_v2.0\Pandora v2.0.exe")

dlg = Desktop().window(title="discord.gg/asakin")
dlg.print_control_identifiers()
```

[image]

I already put `backend="uia"` but the result still same.
Windows SDK already installed. I already try `inspector.exe`, `swapy`, etc but still no luck